# Generate XML with attribute and value in Spark(scala) using databricks

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I wanted to create a nested XML from CSV/DataFrame in scala spark. I am using Databricks spark-XML library for converting the DataFrame to XML format.

I was trying to create an output like below, but unable to achieve it

```
<rows> 
<row>
<name id=10>Mahashree</name>
</row>
</rows>
```

I have tried with struct

```
{"_VALUE":"Mahashree","_id":10}
```

but resulted as below

```
<rows> 
<row>
<name id=10 VALUE="Mahashree"></name>
</row>
</rows>
```

In DataBricks Documentation they have documentation for converting the nested XML but not to nested XML.

```
<one>
    <two myTwoAttrib="BBBBB">two</two>
    <three>three</three>
</one>
```

produces a schema below:

```
root
 |-- two: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _myTwoAttrib: string (nullable = true)
 |-- three: string (nullable = true)
```

can anyone help to the nested element with attributes?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be achieved with two options "attributePrefix" and "valueTag" described here:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

For example, all must be fine if add to stuct additional underscore to "id":

```
{"_VALUE":"Mahashree","__id":10}
```

And save with such options:

```
.option("attributePrefix", "__")
.option("valueTag", "_VALUE")
```